# Php curl very slow

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem with cURL. It takes over 40 seconds to fetch a web page.
The function is:

```
       function get_page(){                 
            $url = get_url();
            $timeout = 1000;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
            curl_setopt($ch, $CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            $return_data = curl_exec($ch);
            print_r (curl_getinfo($ch)); 
            curl_close($ch);
            return $return_data;
        }
```

Also, it seems that $return_data = curl_exec($ch) actually dumps the page.

Comment: On any web page? Or a specific one? Does it work better with a page known to be fast (like, say, stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: What page are you trying to fetch? Have you ruled out the possibility of the bottleneck existing on the server that you're querying or in the network connection?

Comment: It is very slow on every page i try.

Comment: What about a curl from localhost? Try passing in a url like localhost:<your web port>/index.htm

Comment: A curl from localhost is under 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8